# Is ConcurrentHashMap compute() method thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

```
concurrentHashMapInstance.compute("Name", (key, val) -> {
     modifyValWithComplexLogic(val); 
     return val;
});
```

is `modifyValWithComplexLogic(val)` (and the whole `compute` method) thread safe regarding `val`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, yes, but you still need to be careful.

`ConcurrentHashMap#compute` runs the remapping function in a block that's `synchronized` on the node it's about to update, so if the remapping function itself may be racy on another resource and you're calling it on multiple keys, you should probably synchronize it yourself and not assume the `ConcurrentHashMap` will do it for you.

Comment: …and it does not prevent others from doing `get(key).modifyingMethod(…)` at the same time.