# Is it strictly necessary to use atomic integer inside a compute block?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

My doubt is simple. According to other posts this is not thread safe because of the reading+write operation count++. But a compute as far as I know, blocks the entire sector for that key inside the map. So it's impossible that two threads performs this operation at the same time. Why should I use atomic integer or any other concurrent object?

Key can be a profile and the counter it's just a counter for something that can be numeric. Posts, messages, likes...
The structure is a ConcurrentHashMap<Key,Integer>.

```
   counters.compute(key, (key, counter) -> {
        if (counter == null) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return count++;
        }
    });
```

I didn't find any issue executing threads in some tests. But still I don't understand why should I use atomic integer.

Comment: what is `counters`?  What is `count`, or better, how is it declared? What is the mentioned "*sector*"? ... maybe better include a [mre]

Comment: It's just a snippet. Let's say we store counters for profiles, posts, messages... key is a profile and counter is an integer.

Comment: “I didn't find any issue executing threads in some tests.”  The tricky thing about thread safety tests is that you cannot reliably test for such problems.  You just have to write code that cannot, under any circumstances, misbehave in the face of multithreading, or else state in your documentation that the method/class is not thread-safe.  That said, there might be a better way to accomplish your goal, but I’m not sure what that goal is.  Do you really want to replace each non-null Map value with a unique, sequential integer value?

Comment: Thanks VGR. Yes, let's say if you didn't have a counter stored. Then you should add your first "count" there, as 1. In the end it's a silly counter system to persist counters for a given key.

Comment: According to what other posts, and in what context are those posts operating? Assuming you're talking about `ConcurrentHashMap#compute` the entire method should be performed atomically. A potential "gotcha": https://stackoverflow.com/a/67036476/438992

Comment: Sorry I didn't add the structure. Indeed, it's a ConcurrentHashMap#compute. Can I say this is thread safe in that case?

Comment: Use `counters.merge(key, 1, Math::addExact)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is flawed because `return count++;`  increments `count` but returns the previous value - i.e. it never counts up. That line should be `return count + 1;`:

```
counters.compute(key, (k, count) -> {
    if (count == null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return count+1;
    }
});
```

Note that this usage of `ConcurrentHashMap.compute()` (with `Integer` as value) is inherently thread safe:

- the `compute()` function is atomically executed for a specific key - i.e. no other thread can call `compute()` for the same key at the same time and therefore you cannot loose an update.
- concurrent `get()` calls either see the old or the new value depending on the exact timing but (since `Integer` is immutable) they cannot corrupt the count.

---

Using the `merge()` method leads to an even simpler solution (thanks to David Conrad for the hint):

```
counters.merge(key, 1, Math::addExact);
```

This throws an `ArithmeticException` if the counter would overflow. If you want to allow the counter to overflow you can use

```
counters.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: to complete the answer, `return ++count` would have the same effect (returns the result of the `count=count + 1` operation), but is useless, as `count` is a local variable and you don't use it after the `return` - because the method has be left with the `return` statement.

Comment: also, `compute` is overkill for this; this is what `merge` is for: `counters.merge(key, 1, Math::addExact)`. I use `addExact` here instead of `Integer::sum` in the admittedly unlikely  case of integer overflow. I like my code to be correct instead of just happening to work most of the time.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detail explanation.